# How to take changes from remote branch?

Tags: gitlab

I created a branch and pushed it, then merged. My colleague added some code to my branch and said to take it. How can now I update my branch, so it update the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git pull
```

It will update the local version of a repository from a remote.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/git-pull-explained/
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/learn-git-with-bitbucket-cloud

Comment: It works. But need one more advice. Now I again added some code to this branch, pushed it. Will it be seen in MR or I need to merge it again?

Comment: @AlexWhite if the MR is not yet merged or closed, then it will be automatically updated to the latest commit in the branch. If it's already merged or closed then you need to re-open a new MR.